# Increase Dropdown Filtering Efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, filter

I need help making my list filtering more efficient.

I have a ASP.NET MVC application where there is a view for records. I've added a filter option that has a number of dropdowns where, based on the values selected in the dropdowns, filter out the result set of the records. The way I've constructed this filter was based off another filter I've seen but I know there has to be a more effective way to do what I would like to do without taking so many steps or using up as much resource. I can tell this isn't very scalable.

Right now the process involves a number of components.

1. The view, where the results are displayed. Reports.cs
2. The viewModel, to provide data to the view. ReportViewModel.cs
3. The view references a controller that uses a method that references a service method. ReportController.cs using GetReportFilters()
4. The service method refers to another method that pulls all relevant files and filters them GetReportFilters uses RetrieveFilteredReports() located in ReportsService.cs
5. RetrieveFilteredReports() references RetrieveReportsForFilter() Where RetrieveReportsForFilter runs a query against the DB and pulls all needed files. Here are the corresponding code snippets. (edited to save space, change some namespaces, and DB name)

This is a section of the view Reports.cs

```
    <form class="form" asp-action="GetReportFilters" asp-controller="REPORTS">
       <div class = "row"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                Types: @Html.DropDownList("TypeDropdown", new ReportApp.Services.ReportService().GetDropDown("Type"), "select", new { id = "type" })
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                Shift: @Html.DropDownList("ShiftDropdown", new ReportApp.Services.ReportService().GetDropDown("Shift"), "select", new { id = "shifts" })
            </p>
        </div>
     </div>
   </form>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
       
        <th>
            Shift
        </th>
        
        <th>
            Edit
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="cost">

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShiftTimeFound)
        </td>

            <a class="anchorDetail" href="@Url.Action("GetSpecificReport", "Report", new {ReportId = item.ReportId})">
                <i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Here is the snippet from the method referenced in the controller

```
    public ViewResult GetReportFilters(string TypeDropdown, string ShiftDropdown)
    {

        AppContexts.Current.Session.SetObject("TypeDropdown", TypeDropdown);
        AppContexts.Current.Session.SetObject("ShiftDropdown", ShiftDropdown);
        var viewModel = new ReportService().RetrieveFilteredReports(TypeDropdown, ShiftDropdown);
        return View("ReportHistory", viewModel.ToPagedList(p ?? 1, s ?? 10));
    }
```

Here is the RetrieveFilteredReports as referenced in the above method. Also here is and RetrieveReportsForFilter which is referenced in RetrieveFilteredNdrs

```
    public List<ReportViewModel> RetrieveFilteredReports(string TypeName, string Shift)
    {
        var listOfReports = new ReportService().RetrieveReportsForFilter();

        Dictionary<string, string> filterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "TypeName", TypeName },
            { "Shift", Shift  },
        };


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in filterDictionary)
        {
            if (entry.Value != null)
            {
                switch (entry.Key)
                {
                    case "TypeName":
                        listOfReports = listOfReports.Where(x => x.TypeId == entry.Value).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "Shift":
                        listOfNdrs = listOfNdrs.Where(x => x.ShiftTimeId == entry.Value).ToList();
                        break;
        return listOfReports.Select(x => new ReportViewModel
        {
            TypeItemsId = x.TypeId ,
            ShiftId = x.ShiftTimeId 

        }).ToList();

    }


    public List<ReportViewModel> RetrieveReportsForFilter()
    {
        var listOfAudits = new List<ReportViewModel>();
        using var context = new ReportContext();//contains the formatting for fields
        var dropdowns = context.DB.AsNoTracking().ToList();//replaced actually db name with just DB
        var query = context.Reports.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        listOfAudits = query.Select(x => new ReportViewModel
        {
            TypeId = x.ReportType,
            ShiftTimeId = x.ShiftTimeFound,
          
        }).ToList();
        return listOfAudits;
    }
```

As you can see the code bounces around quite a bit. As more and more entries are added to the DB it'll get continually slower until it becomes unbearable. How can I improve the efficiency of this process for scalability?

If there is any more needed information please let me know.

Comment: There are some comments here that might help u. First of all : var dropdowns = context.DB.AsNoTracking().ToList(); I don't see any use for it. Just load from DB. Second I see it is about an audit table and makes sense to be large. The DB should be well build with Indexes defined on the search fields. For UI you should use pagination and then build the BL accordingly to prevent bringing all table items. The filter conditions will be applying on the DB query and not on the items that were fresh loaded from DB.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. Can you clarify some more on the second half of your comment about using pagination then building the list accordingly? Can you detail some more for me on how will I avoid bringing all table items by filtering the DB query? I can see that being the biggest slow down on the process.

Comment: Read some tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application